# Doubts about the Eishet Chayil

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

> "She seeks out wool and linen, and her hands work willingly"
>
> "דרשה צמר ופשתים, ותעש בחפץ כפיה"

Why would it be allowed for the eishet chayil to make shatnez? Does she serve milk and meat, too?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed to make shatnez? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60320/759

Comment: @DoubleAA No serious answers to a Purim Torah question!!!! Ahem

Comment: I agree with that. I posted a comment critiquing this question as not that funny.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, it's not allowed. That's why it says, a bit further along:

> רַבּוֹת בָּנוֹת עָשׂוּ חָיִל וְאַתְּ עָלִית עַל כֻּלָּנָה שֶׁקֶר
>
> "Many women have done well, but you have surpassed them all." Lies!

Answer (score 5):

See later on in the song (Proverbs 31:23)

> נוֹדָע בַּשְּׁעָרִים בַּעְלָהּ; בְּשִׁבְתּוֹ, עִם-זִקְנֵי-אָרֶץ.

Her husband is on the Sanhedrin. The Talmud teaches (Eruvin 13b) that the elders of the Sanhedrin were able to be "מטהר את השרץ" i.e. argue away biblical prohibitions through causistry. This one's wife decided to take the pilpul seriously!

Answer (score 3):

Obviously she is one of the women who will be weaving the Bigdei Kehuna for the coming Beis Hamikdash (bimheira b'yameinu) which are required to be made out of Shatnez. Only the best of women, chachmei lev, will be allowed to do this.